# Regex ignore everything inside several sets of symbols

Tags: regex

What would be the optimal way to set regex to extract text from the following expressions:

```
This is my text about [one] (two) {three} things.
[one] {three} This is my text about things.
This is my text [one] about {two} things.
This is my text {three} about (two) things.
This is my text about things. {three} [one]
```

resulting in

```
This is my text about things.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely a duplicate question but I can't find a good fit for this so here is my approach:

Instead of "extracting the text" look for **"removing everything between symbols"**. You can do that with something like this (used JS but it is very similar in any other language):

```js
text = `This is my text about [one] (two) {three} things.
[one] {three} This is my text about things.
This is my text [one] about {two} things.
This is my text {three} about (two) things.
This is my text about things. {three} [one]`

output = text
  .replace(/\[.*\]/gm, "") // Remove everything between []
  .replace(/\(.*\)/gm, "") // And between ()
  .replace(/\{.*\}/gm, "") // And between {}
  .replace(/ {2,}/gm, " ") // Convert things like "   " to " "
  .replace(/^ {1,}/gm, "") // Convert things like "  This" to "This"

console.log(output)
```

Comment: That's a nice perspective of looking at it, thank you @adelriosantiago

Comment: To avoid removing too much in case a pattern occurs more than once, change from greedy `/\[.*\]/gm` to non-greedy `/\[.*?\]/gm` pattern